$f(x)$ must be a straight line?

Let $f :[0 , 10] \rightarrow [10 , 20]$ be a continuous and twice differentiable function such that $f(0)=10$ and $f(10)=20$ .Suppose $|f '(x)| \le 1$ for all $x\in [0 ,10]$ .Then the value of $f'(5) $.
My Attmept :
I will show $f(x)=x+10 ,x \in [c_n , 10]$ where ${c_n}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence in $[0 ,10)$ converging to $0$ .

Proof :
We must have $\forall x,y \in [0, 10]$
Then $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|$
or
$|f(x)| \le 10+x$ since $x>0 \space ...(1)$
By Mean Value Theorem  $\exists c_1 \in (0 ,10)$ such that $f '(c_1)=\frac{f(10)-f(0)}{10-0} =1 $
Now
Thus $f'(x)$ attains it supremum at $c_1$ .
The equation of the tangent line at $f(c_1)$ is given by
$y=x+f(c_1)-c_1$
We define a function $h(x)$ on $[c_1 , 10]$ by
$h(x)=f(x)-(x+f(c_1)-c_1)  $
Then $h(c_1)=0$
Now by $(1)$ , we have $f(c _1)\le c_1+10$
Which gives $h(10) \ge 0$ .
Again $h'(x)=f'(x)-1\le 0, \forall x \in [c_1, 10]$
Thus $h(x)$ is monotone decreasing on$[c_1, 10]$ and hence we get
$0=h(c_1)\ge h(x)\ge h(10)\ge 0 , \forall x \in [c_1 , 10]$
So $h(x)$ becomes identically zero on $[c_1 , 10]$ and $f(x)=x+f(c_1)-c_1$, that is $f(x)$ becomes a straight line on $[c_1, 10]$
Putting $x=10$ in above , we get
$f(c_1)= c_1+10$
Applying above technique to the interval $[0, c_1]$ with $f(0)=10, f(c_1)=c_1+10$ ,
I get $0< c_2 < c_1$ such that $f(x)$ becomes the straight line $x+f(c_2)-c_2$ on $[ c_2 , c_1]$
Proceeding similarly , we must $c_k <5 $ so $f$ is a straight line at $5$ with slope $1$ and hence $f'(5)=1$
Summary :I have shown f becomes straight lines on sequence of compact intervals with slope 1 .
My Doubt is if proceeding in above way the function $f(x)$ will uniformly converge to  the straight line $x+10$ . Are there alternate ways to prove $f$ is a straight line or not ?
Very sure I am overlooking or missing something as there is no use of double derivative.
Hints Please.

I wouldn’t assume the solution necessarily needs to use all the information provided. However your solution seems very complicated. Suggested hint: consider the fundamental theorem of calculus.

I added the solution-verification tag since that's essentially what you're asking for. Per the rules, please "identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so".

You don't overlook something.
Your proof seems fine but overcomplicated… there is no need of second derivative here as well.
I would solve it like this:
Assume $f(x) \not= x + 10$ then there exists $x_0 \in (0,10)$ s.t. $f(x_0) \not= x_0 + 10$.
If $f(x_0) > x_0 + 10$ then for a $\xi \in (0,x_0)$
$$f'(\xi) = \frac{f(x_0) - f(0)}{x_0 - 0} > \frac{x_0 + 10 - 10}{x_0} = 1$$ If $f(x_0) < x_0 + 10$ then for a $\xi \in (x_0,10)$
$$f'(\xi) = \frac{f(10) - f(x_0)}{10 - x_0} > \frac{20 - x_0 - 10}{10 - x_0} = 1$$
which contradicts $|f'(x)| \le 1$ for $x\in [0,10]$ hence the assumption was incorrect and so $f(x) = x+10$ and $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

Ahhh ! Indeed  Beautiful proof . Thank you .
